# Cannot update Interaction using Fuel REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, fuel

I can't get the putUpdateInteraction method to work as per the [documentation](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/interaction/putUpdateInteraction.html). I'm simply just trying to update an Interaction description.

### Request

Here's the request that I'm using:

```
HOST: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
PUT /interaction/v1/interactions/0c58a686-c953-4ebc-86f2-242c39ac7b8d
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "id": "0c58a686-c953-4ebc-86f2-242c39ac7b8d",
    "modifiedDate": "2015-01-15T00:48:07.223",
    "description": "An updated description of my Interaction.",
    "version": 1,
    "workflowApiVersion": 1.0
}
```

### Response

```
{"message":"Oops. We’ve encountered an error. Please retry the action or contact support.","errorcode":30000,"documentation":""}
```

### Documentation Issues

I believe there are a few issues with the documentation:

1. Path to method is incorrect. It reads `/interaction/v1/interactions/interactions/` but should be `/interaction/v1/interactions/`
2. In the JSON Parameters section of the documentation, modifiedDate is not required, but apparently it is required.
3. The documentation mentions the URL parameter `?versionNumber=2` in the request, but this is not mentioned in the URL Parameters section of the documentation. I've tried including this parameter but it doesn't seem to help.

Please can someone confirm what is the correct syntax for this request?

Comment: I see the `/interaction/v1/interactions/interactions/` typo has now been corrected in the documentation, however I am still dying to update an interaction. If anyone can figure out how to get this method to work I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I opened a support case on 3Sixty for this issue, but received a response "Support is not the proper resource to assist in helping writing an API call." Quite frustrating, particularly as they have a 'REST API' category when creating a support ticket (I assumed this meant I can get support when the API does not work). I'm really hoping someone is able to shed some light on how I can get this method to work properly.

Comment: For the version number, I believe this relates back to the JB Interaction Version you are attempting to update.  Does your Interaction have multiple versions and is the one you are attempting to update currently running?   Think errorcode you mention is:  "Ensure you provide the correct route."  id, name, version, and workflowApiVersion are all required for this call I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get this to work with using something similar to the below.  I just did a few tests in my SOAPUI environment and was able to make updates each time.  ModifiedDate is needed and you would want to use the last time the interaction was modified.  You may need to retrieve this but I obtained it after I initially did a POST request to create a new interaction.

I also had to include just the Key or both the KEY & ID when I was testing. Only thing I included in my Query String Parameters was "access_token".

```
{
    "key": "ixn-created-via-the-api",
    "modifiedDate": "2015-01-22T14:14:39.433",
    "name": "API-Created Interaction",
    "version": 1,
    "description": "This is just a test Description",
    "workflowApiVersion": 1.0 
}
```

Link to the workflow info is below as well:
https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/workflow-format/getting-started.html

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, this works! The issue is that [the documentation](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/interaction/putUpdateInteraction.html) states that `key` and `id` are required as **URL parameters** but it appears these are ignored. It also states that `id` is a required **json parameter**. But it's not; you can optionally include an `id` key/value pair as a json parameter, but the `key` json parameter is always required.